# Protractor - X is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

In Protractor I'm trying to run a function from another page inside my spec file.

My spec file:

```
let TablePage = require("./../pages/TablePage");
let table_page = new TablePage();
let protractor = require("protractor");
let browser = protractor.browser;

   describe('Login', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            browser.waitForAngular();
            jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
            browser.get("/budget");
        });

        it('should get values from list', function(){
            table_page.getPriceValuesFromList();
        });
```

The other file form which i get the function (TablePage.js):

```
let protractor = require("protractor");
let browser = protractor.browser;
let number = 0;
let prices = [];

let TablePage = (function () {
  function TablePage() {

  }

  TablePage.prototype.getPriceValuesFromList = function () {
    for (number = 1; number < 100; number++) {
      let locator = '//*[@id="root"]/main/section/table/tbody/tr[' + number + ']/td[3]/div[2]';
      browser.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).then(function (err) {
        prices[number] = element(By.xpath(locator)).getText();
        console.log(prices[number])
      }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          break;
        }
      })
    }
  };

  return TablePage;

});
module.exports = TablePage;
```

**I get an error: table_page.getPriceValuesFromList is not a function**

Do you know what's wrong? I was doing it this way in the other project and it was working.
The real typeof() this function is undefined

You can also check if the function will work - it should get values from one row of the table, save it in array and go to the next row until the value inside row is not found - Save values form the column

Comment: There is an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366994/javascript-protractor-seeing-outside-functions-as-undefined

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of lines which shouldn't be there. TablePage should be defined as follows:

```
function TablePage() { }

// Removed lines which were here.

TablePage.prototype.getPriceValuesFromList = function () {
    for (number = 1; number < 100; number++) {
        let locator = '//*[@id="root"]/main/section/table/tbody/tr[' + number + ']/td[3]/div[2]';
        browser.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).then(function (err) {
            prices[number] = element(By.xpath(locator)).getText();
            console.log(prices[number])
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                break;
            }
        })
    }
};

// And removed the return TablePage();
```

As an object orientalist I prefer implementation using classes:

```
class TablePage {

    getPriceValuesFromList() {
        for (number = 1; number < 100; number++) {
            let locator = '//*[@id="root"]/main/section/table/tbody/tr[' + number + ']/td[3]/div[2]';
            browser.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).then(function (err) {
                prices[number] = element(By.xpath(locator)).getText();
                console.log(prices[number])
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    break;
                }
            })
        }
    };

};
```

Comment: With first solution: the same error, with second solution should I remove "let table_page = new TablePage();" from spec file? how should I invoke the function? I'm getting TablePage is not a constructor

Comment: Independent of the solution you need to instantiate `TablePage` like you did in the spec file. Both solutions work on my computer, though I didn't actually run protractor, just checked if the class and function could be resolved, which succeeded in both implementations. Nothing wrong with you function invocation as far as I can see. Note that you should still export the TablePage as you did on the last line.

Comment: Ah, I think what is the problem, did you remove `return TablePage;`, just above the export?

Comment: no it's not the problem with return, i removed it and still it does't see the contents of the TablePage, all the elements are undefined, even the locators, when i try to run from spec file this.text = table_page.workingBalanceField.getText(); i get Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined, seems something's wrong with the import or function at the beginning of the TablePage

Comment: I'm pretty sure that removing `return TablePage` solves the initial problem. I successfully ran the code here without all protractor related stuff, because that wasn't related to it. The code you refer to in your comments seems to be new, it's not present in the original code. I would suggest to create a new question for the new error.

Comment: when i run let text = element(By.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/section/div/div/div[5]/div/div[1]')).getText(); expect(text.toMatch("/d{0-3}?,?/d{0-3}?/.?/d{0-3}?")); I get text.toMatch is not a function, it doesn't see even frunction from jasmine-node package, although it can run the test and open the browser,

Comment: I can also open the pages by holding ctrl and clicking on the function name, and it's markey yellow, what packages did you install to run the code without protractor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180153/discussion-between-jedrek-cienicki-and-bouke).

Comment: If you don't mind, I have other plans for Sunday evening. I'm sure you will solve the problem eventually.

Comment: yes, thanks for your response, i'm also not working now, but if you could look at it tomorrow if will be cool