# Javascript Protractor - Seeing outside functions as undefined

Tags: javascript, function, protractor, automated-tests

> In specs/Test.js is a test definition: "regex2"
>
> In pages/TablePage.js is a page object

in regex2 there is a try to use a function from TablePage.js

```
   it('regex2', function(){
            table_page.matchPriceRegex(table_page.workingBalanceField)
        });
```

it is saying     `table_page.matchPriceRegex is not a function`

The function itself from TablePage.js:

```
var TablePage = (function () {

  function TablePage() {
    this.workingBalanceField = element(By.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/section/div/div/div[5]/div/div[1]'));
  }

  TablePage.prototype.matchPriceRegex = function (locator) {
    this.text = locator.getText();
    expect(this.text).toMatch("\d{0,3}?,?\d{0,3}?\.?\d{0,3}?");
  };
});
module.exports = TablePage;
```

The require's are incorporated with the spec file so it should see it

```
var TablePage = require("./../pages/TablePage");
var table_page = new TablePage();
var protractor = require("protractor");
var jasmine = require("jasmine-node");
var browser = protractor.browser;
var number = 0;
```

When in my IDE(WebStorm) I hold ctrl and click on the function name it redirects me correctly, as it sees it

The typeof the functions or variables form TablePage is undefined

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question, take the [tour] (you get a badge!), and read through [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What ide are you using? What default libraries is it loading? Are you missing a require or mock of something?

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `TablePage.js`, it should be.

```
var TablePage = (function () {

  function TablePage() {
    this.workingBalanceField = element(By.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/section/div/div/div[5]/div/div[1]'));
  }

  TablePage.prototype.matchPriceRegex = function (locator) {
    this.text = locator.getText();
    expect(this.text).toMatch("\d{0,3}?,?\d{0,3}?\.?\d{0,3}?");
  };

  return TablePage; // return the class as outer function return value
})(); 
// `(function(...){})` return a function, you should use `()` to execute the
// return function to get the returned class: TablePage.

module.exports = TablePage;
```